# Using list of objects to pass between layers of the project (C#)

Tags: c#, oop

In a C# (visual Studio 2010) project, I have a class with large number of properties, and I populate objects of this class with data and add to list object to pass it to display list of items (Something like results of a search).
My problem is there I don't need all the properties of the class to display the above list, so do I have to create another class only with required field to display the (results) list? Is it correct according to the OOP concepts?

Comment: Is it expensive to move data between the layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your properties object can implement multiple interfaces, as requested by different parts of your program.

If you define these interfaces:

```
public interface IBasicInfo
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Id { get; }
}

internal interface IFullInfo : IBasicInfo
{
    string Address { get; }
}

internal interface IInternalStuff
{
    Stuff Data { get; }
}
```

And your properties class implements them like this:

```
internal class Properties : IFullInfo, IInternalStuff
{
    // some basic implementation
}
```

Then you can pass this class to a different part of your app which has a method like this:

```
public void Display(IBasicInfo info)
{
   ...
}
```

And the calling code will only see properties which belong to `IBasicInfo`. Note that only `IBasicInfo` needs to be public, and even the `Properties` class is **internal** to ensure that no calling code can cast back to the actual implementation and mess with it.

Alternatively, if your calling code contains completely different interfaces, then it is perfectly reasonable to convert them into Data Transfer Objects, and even modify their contents to match caller's expectations (adapter pattern). There are tools which automate this task ([Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), for example).

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, it is called [Data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a solution like [automapper](http://automapper.org/) to map from a class that has N number of properties to another that has M number of properties.  It relies on some conventional information (same/similar name) but can be tweaked too.

This is a pretty standard way of taking model data pulled from a DB and converting it into something that can be displayed on a view in webpage.  I build a "viewmodel" that just has the stuff I want to display, which is typically a subset of the fields, and then map between them.  Something like automapper makes it pretty easy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a reference type (a class), it shouldn't be costly to pass the original object rather than a new object containing a subset of the data.

If you want to protect the object from being manipulated by the recipient of the list, then you could define a read-only interface for the class, and pass it as that.